# Ordenar una tabla por medio de una relación en ORM Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql, laravel-7, relaciones

tengo un problema para ordenar una tabla, la quiero ordenar de forma ASC por campo **name** de la tabla (farms) que en este caso es una relación del modelo **MasterInvoiceItem**.

Esta es mi consulta:

> Route::get('/invoicesitems/{id}', function($id){
> $invoiceItems = MasterInvoiceItem::with('farm')->with('variety')->where('id_load', $id)->get();
> return $invoiceItems;
> });

Este es mi modelo MasterInvoiceItem:

```
class MasterInvoiceItem extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_invoiceh', 
        'id_client', 
        'id_farm', 
        'id_load', 
        'variety_id', 
        'hawb', 
        'pieces',
        'hb',
        'qb',
        'eb', 
        'stems', 
        'price',
        'bunches', 
        'fulls',    
        'total',
        'id_user',
        'update_user',
        'stems_p_bunches'
    ];

    public function farm()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Farm', 'id_farm');
    }

    public function variety()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Variety', 'variety_id');
    }
}
```

Modelo Farm:

```
class Farm extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'phone',
        'address',
        'state', // Estado
        'city', // Ciudad
        'country',
        'id_user',
        'update_user'
    ];

    public function masterinvoiceitems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\MasterInvoiceItem', 'id_farm');
    }
}
```

Como decia anteriormente deseo ordenar por el campo *name* de la relacion (farm) de forma ASC.

Comment: Ya edite la consulta, espero esté mas entendible.

Comment: Intente con eso, pero no me funciona. $invoiceItems = MasterInvoiceItem::with([
        'farm' => function ($q){
            $q->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
        }])->with('variety')->where('id_load', $id)->get();

Comment: Me devuelve la consulta que quiero, pero no me la ordena de forma ascendente por el **name** de la tabla **farms**, que es lo que quiero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos pude solucionar gracias a el aporte de Warkeys WK, me compartio [esta pagina](https://www.mynotepaper.com/laravel-order-by-relationship-column-with-example)

```
Route::get('/invoicesitems/{id}', function($id){
    $invoiceItems = MasterInvoiceItem::select('*')
        ->where('id_load', '=', $id)
        ->with('variety')
        ->join('farms', 'master_invoice_items.id_farm', '=', 'farms.id')
        ->orderBy('farms.name', 'ASC')
        ->get();
    return $invoiceItems;
});
```